# Extrude Tool Not Creating New Face

Tags: extrude

Please pardon my lack of knowledge on lingo (yes im new), but im having an issue with the extrude tool. In the fundamental tutorials it explained to me how to (in this example) create a stack of blocks with the extrude tool and that the tool will basically create a new face on the surface of the previous cube for you to adjust the size, raise up, and repeat. It was working at first but now the tool, instead of creating the new face for a new cube, is adjusting the original face of the first cube and thereby changing the shape of the entire cube into basically a pyramid. What am i missing here? First picture is my issue while the second is my desired outcome

[image: first picture showing my issue]

[image: second showing my desired outcome]

Comment: Can you try extruding with E key?

Comment: In the first image you are not extruding, but resizing/moving a face. To extrude select the face, press "E" and pull with the mouse'

Comment: I would guess that in the first image you are using the extrude tool then pressing ctrl z to return the face to its origin? this would undo both the extrusion and the location of the extrusion in the second sequence you click the right mouse button while still holding the extrusion with the left mouse button to release the extrusion so it is still there to be scaled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lower example takes two steps.

First Extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, then scale <kbd>S</kbd> inwards.

Then extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, and pull (transform) <kbd>G</kbd> upwards on `Z` axis.

[image]

*You may find it simpler to use inset <kbd>I</kbd> instead of extrude for the first step to shorten steps.* [image]

Comment: Awesome! i knew it was a simple answer but for the life of me i couldnt figure it out lol

Comment: Welcome, glad to help :)